# Unable to Register Namespace for QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to register a file including only a namespace with `qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject` for use in `QML`

The Namespace is in my `constants.h` file which looks as follows:

```
#ifndef K_CONSTANTS_H
#define K_CONSTANTS_H
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

static const QString K_Red = "#d20019";
static const QString K_DarkRed = "#a20000";
static const QString K_Green = "#1da019";
static const QString K_DarkGray = "#FF4b4b4b";

static const unsigned int EXIT_CODE_REBOOT = 1234567890;

namespace Strings {
    Q_NAMESPACE
    static const char* REPAIR = QT_TR_NOOP("Repair");
    static const char* MAINTENANCE = QT_TR_NOOP("Maintenance");
    static const char* DISTURBANCE = QT_TR_NOOP("Disturbance");
    static const char* MEAL_BREAK = QT_TR_NOOP("Meal Break");
}

#endif // K_CONSTANTS_H
```

I am trying to register with in the constructor of `K_Administration.cpp` which is called before the `app.exec()` is called.

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject(Strings::staticMetaObject, "MyConstants", 1, 0, "Strings", "Not Instantiable!" );
```

this always results in

> k_administration.obj:-1: Error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "struct QMetaObject const Strings::staticMetaObject"
>   (?staticMetaObject@Strings@@3UQMetaObject@@B)

I can access the Namespace from everywhere in my project. It is also possible to call just `Strings::staticMetaObject`. but it seems to fail as soon as `Strings::staticMetaObject` is assigned to a value.

Maybe it is important to know that `K_Administration.cpp` and `K_Constants.h` are in 2 different subprojects of my project

Comment: have you re-run qmake since updating your header? I guess there should be a `constants_moc.cpp` or similar file which should contain the definition of Strings::staticMetaObject

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes i tried to re-run qmake and there is a  `moc_k_constants.cpp` . I also tried to rebuild the whole project.

Comment: Apart from not linking, the static "strings" will not be exposed to QML. What is it that you are trying to do in the end?

Comment: @Amfasis I would like to create a file for all strings to use them in c++ and QML. As i want to call those strings without class identifier in c++ I was thinking of a namespace.

Comment: Then, why not set up a translation mechanism: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-internationalization.html ? (seeing you already used `QT_TR_NOOP`) You will have one file (xml) with all the text that can even be translated by third parties. True, it will take a bit of effort, but it will definitely pay of once your program becomes big (not sure of your intentions here of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `K_Administration` and `K_Constants` are in two different projects it is necassary to add an export delcaration. This can be in an other file and inlcuded or in the same file.

```
#if defined(CONSTANTS_LIBRARY)
#  define CONSTANTS_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define CONSTANTS_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

to export the namespace i it its necassary to add it to the namespace

```
CONSTANTS_EXPORT Q_NAMESPACE
```

**NOTE:** I made the mistake that i wanted to add the `CONSTANTS_EXPORT` declaration to the namespace definition line. something like  `namespace CONSTANTS_EXPORT Strings {}` because there is a similar syntax for `classes`. but in a `namespace` it a declaration for `Q_NAMESPACE`. I think it is possible to use `Q_NAMESPACE_EXPORT` and leave the export declaration for **Qt 5.14** and above.